# Class Config conflict in XAMPP xamppfiles/lib/php/config.php

Tags: php, xampp

What is *xamppfiles/lib/php* for?
And I see that path is in PHP's *include_path* but it's not set in *php.ini* so I guess XAMPP includes it internally.
What do those php files do and why are they included by default?

I just installed an application that does `include('config.php');` trying to reference a file from the same directory it's in, but ends up including *xamppfiles/lib/php/config.php* instead and has a name clash with class *Config*.

How can I avoid including XAMPP's php files or otherwise avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "Config" pear package that comes with XAMPP. This package ships the "Config.php" file that uses the same name that your application.

```
sudo xamppfiles/bin/pear uninstall Config
```